# Vertical-inclied list of elements ( or divs) - AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of 15 elements, which I am repeating through with ng-repeat. I would like to display them as a list or divs is kinda of a weird order like this(each number represents the 'index'):

```
 1  4  7  10  14 
   2  5  8  11  12
     3  6  9   13  15
```

- they have to be indented just like this.
  Is there any way to do this with angular/bootstrap/css rather than splitting things up on API side?

Comment: Solved it myself in very tricky(API side would be the best solution) way but it's working - so I will write the answer if anyone would be looking. I wrote 3 ng-repeats and I am showing only with $index that I would like to. So for the first line that would be :                                                          <div ng-show="$index == 0 || $index == 3 || $index == 6 || $index == 9 || $index == 11">{{$index}} </div>

Comment: You could write an answer to your question yourself for helping future visitors (although your problem is very specific to you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself in very tricky(API side would be the best solution) way but it's working - so I will write the answer if anyone would be looking. I wrote 3 ng-repeats and I am showing only with $index that I would like to. So for the first line that would be : {{$index}}